# How can I use page.js with Svelte and Vite?

Tags: svelte, page.js

I've set up a pretty simple Svelte app. It uses page.js for routing, and uses Vite as the build tool. There's a map of california on the landing page.

When I'm running the app locally via `npm run dev`, I can either click on a county OR use the dropdown to navigate to a county page.

However, when I build the site with npm run build ([as you can see here on Netlify](https://splendid-yeot-baf72e.netlify.app/)), I can't use the dropdown-- I get a 404. And if I try to go directly to a county page (e.g. https://splendid-yeot-baf72e.netlify.app/county/Colusa), I also get a 404.

The full code can be viewed on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hawking-5fgpjt?file=/App.svelte) (where it actually works, making this more frustrating)

How do I fix this? I have done a lot of searching and not found an answer.

The router is called from App.svelte:

```
    <script lang="ts">
      import router from "page";
      import State from "./pages/State.svelte";
      import County from "./pages/County.svelte";

      let page;
      let params;

      router("/", () => (page = State));
      router(
        "/county/:id",
        (ctx, next) => {
          params = ctx.params;
          next();
        },
        () => (page = County)
      );

      router.start();
    </script>

    <div id="center">
      <svelte:component this={page} {params} />
      <main />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CountrySelect` component does a hard page load with `window.location.href = ...`, so you need to make sure [Netlify serves your `index.html` file for all routes](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps), so that the `page` library can take over the routing in the browser.

Additionally, you could also [have `page` itself handle the navigation to avoid the hard page load](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js#pagepath) to make it a true SPA.